# Resolving Target Names from Storyboard in Resource Dictionary in Silverlight Navigation App

Tags: silverlight

I have a Storyboard that animates an Ellipse on a navigation:Page control. As long as I keep the Storyboard local inside the UserControl.Resources the animation runs with no problem.

I moved the Storyboard into a Resource Dictionary to make it available to multiple pages. I can access the Storyboard as expected, but the application throws an exception when the Storyboard attempts to locate the element to animate. I get a 'Cannot resolve TargetName' error.

My guess is that since this is a Silverlight navigation application the Storyboard needs to know about the application hierarchy to get to the page to find the final target - I just don't know how to make that happen :)

Answer (score 0):

Does it use any inherited styles? I havehad this exact problem when using inherited styles. If I move it all to the same resource dictionary or all in the user control, it then works fine.

If not, post a code sample and I can take a look.

Comment: I tried adding my StoryBoard to the Styles.xaml file that was pre-defined as a ResourceDictionary, but that didn't seem to work.

I have pasted my code here for you to take a look at: http://codepaste.net/xwq6bn

I am guessing that the best way to deal with this is to just add the glyph and the StoryBoard into a user control and just reuse that in the application. Does that sound appropriate?