# Packaging Storyboards

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am developing a WPF application which consists of a single window and many animations. These animations are split up into six of so different storyboards which work fine when placed in the  section. My problem is that I want to somehow take these storyboards and put them somewhere else, like in their own file. This produces less cluttered code and makes it reusable. I learned that storyboards can't reside in a ResourceDirectory but is there some other way of splitting storyboards that I don't know about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are we SURE Storyboards can't be in a ResourceDictionary?  I feel like I've done this myself.  [Also, this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447124/resolving-target-names-from-storyboard-in-resource-dictionary-in-silverlight-nav)

Comment: I have a bunch of storyboards defined in ResourceDictionaries which are included in the Application via MergedDictionaries however I have no idea how to get that Storyboard object in code-behind without it crashing due to an IllegalOperationException.

Comment: Are they entirely free of statically set targets?

Comment: They are entirely free, here is an example: http://pastebin.com/p7uSDPYp. I call these by doing something like uiStoryboardTile.Begin (myTarget); or uiStoryboardTile.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);

Comment: I noticed that the problem is only when I try to modify the animation such as BeginTime. It works when I call Begin (target). And that's understandable. As for retrieving the Storyboards, FindResource does the trick. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider creating a behavior to encapsulate these animations. What I normally do is, translate my storyboards into c# code, then put them into a behavior.

If you think translating these animations into c# is a bit of work you might also try putting your xaml code into a readonly string, something like this,

```
internal static readonly string MyStoryboard =
@"<Storyboard xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"">
    <DoubleAnimation Duration=""0"" To=""1"" Storyboard.TargetProperty=""(UIElement.Opacity)"" Storyboard.TargetName=""LayoutRoot"" />
</Storyboard>";
```

and then just use XmlReader.Load to load it. Something like this,

```
_storyboard = XamlReader.Load(Storyboards.MyStoryboard) as Storyboard;
```

Hope this helps. :)